# What does the percentage represent in linear-gradient : CSS?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

What is the meaning of the 0% and 100% in the following CSS code ?

`background : linear-gradient (to left , rgba (7,27,82,1) 0% , rgba (0,128,128,1) 100%);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you specify the location as a percentage, 0% represents the starting point, while 100% represents the ending point; however, you can use values outside that range if necessary to get the effect you want. If you leave a location unspecified, the position of that particular color stop will be automatically calculated for you, with the first color stop being at 0% and the last color stop being at 100%, and any other color stops being half way between their adjacent color stops.

source : `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients`

Answer (score 1):

They are the starting and ending points (you can additionally add more color stops).